# Adding https in URL takes to different site

Tags: website, dns-hosting

I have a domain www.abc.co.in mapped with default index page. but, when i add `https` in the url to https://www.abc.co.in, it takes to someone else's site. Does it have to be any configuration problem in DNS mapping? Please let me know your views

Comment: You're likely on shared hosting. This happens there. Get a VPS.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is if you're missing a virtual host for a domain in Apache (i.e. a virtual host for www.abc.co.in for HTTPS - 443), then accessing a a subdomain pointing to the webserver will display the first virtual host from the Apache configuration. In this case what I assume is happening is that you don't have a virtual host for your domain on port 443 and you're sharing an IP with someone else, so when you access the website through HTTPS, since it can't find that specific virtual host, the first one in the Apache config is being served.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Apache webserver as basis, it can also be due to the Apache web server / security settings.

Check the rerouting / SSL configuration of your apache installation and verify the if you added the correct target URL.